# Google Cloud Platform Charging $10 for loading a Dataset of 2G

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I started a VM instance for an ML task that needs to train a model on a 2G data set. I use connected the VM to Google's datalab and loaded the 2G dataset using from GCP's bucket. The VM has a standard "n1-highmem-16" machine type.

Datalab automatically disconnects in 1-2 hrs, but I was charged $10 for simply loading the 2G data to the memory. I was wondering if it was because I did not shut down the VM soon enough so there was an on-going charge, so I reload the same dataset again and monitored the charges. I found that I was charged $2 in 2 minutes for that task. I expect the on-going charges to accumulate fast.

These confusing charges basically makes it impossible for me to finish a project completely on GCP. Does anyone have suggestions on anything that I have done wrong in creating the VM or handling the task so that I got charged this much? If not, does anyone have a suggestions for more reasonable cloud computing sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach out to the GCP [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) regarding your issue with billing of charges for GCP resources. In the meanwhile, you can look into the [GCP Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/pricing) in order to have a better understanding on the specific pricing for different resources.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to open a issuetracker case or billing team of gcp for better overview of the incurred charges